# How to detect Form Resize END, maybe by using the TApplicationEvents component?

Tags: forms, delphi, window-resize, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4 VCL Application, I need to detect when the FORM RESIZING **ENDS**. (E.g. after the user resized the Form by dragging its size-grip).

So I have placed a `TApplicationEvents` component on the form and created its `OnMessage` event-handler, trying to catch the `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` message:

```
procedure TformMain.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if (Msg.Message = WM_EXITSIZEMOVE) then
  begin
    CodeSite.Send('TformMain.ApplicationEvents1Message: WM_EXITSIZEMOVE');
  end;
end;
```

But the event-handler with `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` is not executed after resizing the Form.

So how can I detect the Form Resize END, maybe by using the TApplicationEvents component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-exitsizemove) message is *sent* directly to the window. Thus, it is not detected by the `TApplicationEvents`'s [`OnMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.AppEvnts.TCustomApplicationEvents.OnMessage) handler, because that only detects messages that are *posted* to the main message queue.

So, you need to override the form's `WndProc()` instead:

```pascal
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  public
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
      ShowMessage('Yes!');
  end;
end;
```

Or, you can use a [`message` procedure](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Message_Methods) instead:

```pascal
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
  protected
    procedure WMExitSizeMove(var Message: TMessage); message WM_EXITSIZEMOVE;
  public
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.WMExitSizeMove(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('Yes!');
end;
```

However, beware that this message, as its name implies, is not only sent when the window has been resized, but it is also sent after the window has been moved.  And in both cases, only when the operation involved a modal loop.

For instance, if you maximize the window by double-clicking its title bar, or if you move it to a different screen by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, this message isn't sent at all.

Comment: In the case of maximize and keyboard movement, there are other messages you can intercept instead, like `WM_SYSCOMMAND`, `WM_MOV(ING|E)`, `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANG(ING|ED)`. Note that there is also `WM_SIZ(ING|E)` messages, too.

Comment: To differentiate between MOVING and RESIZING a Form, I would need to COMPARE the Form's size BEFORE it starts resizing and AFTER it has been resized. (I am only interested in RESIZING). So how can I catch the Form Resize Start (just before it has started resizing)?

Comment: @user1580348: `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`, perhaps?